# Total and subtotal calculations

Tags: calculations, totalcount

I am writing a series of tests in LaTeX, and I was wondering if LaTeX could calculate the total marks and the number of questions.

Ideally I would like it to do the following:

Let's say Question 1 is made up of three parts worth 2, 4 and 1 mark respectively, then I would like LaTeX to print the total marks for this question was 7 marks.

If Question 2 is made up of four parts worth 3, 2, 1 and 4, then I would like LaTeX to print the total marks for this question was 10 marks.

I'd then like LaTeX to print the total number of questions was 2 and the total marks was 17.

I could calculate each total etc manually but since questions are can be interchanged and marks adjusted (each question is stored as it's own file and inserted using the \input command), calculating totals manually would be inefficient.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, openany]{memoir} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\begin{document} 
\textbf{Section One (40 marks)} \\ This section has \textbf{three (3)} questions. Answer all questions. \textbf{Question 1 (6 marks)} (a) First part (2 marks)\\ (b) Second part (3 marks)\\ (c) Third part (1 mark)\\ \textbf{Question 2 (10 marks)} (a) First part (3 marks)\\ (b) Second part (4 marks)\\ (c) Third part (2 mark)\\ (d) Fourth part (1 mark)\\ \textbf{Question 3 (5 marks)} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  A [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of how you currently produce your tests would be really helpful.

Comment: You might be interested in one of the dedicated packages/ classes such as `exam` or `xsim`.

Comment: \documentclass[11pt, twoside, openany]{memoir}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Section One (40 marks)}
\\
This section has \textbf{three (3)} questions. Answer all questions.

\textbf{Question 1 (6 marks)}

(a) First part (2 marks)\\
(b) Second part (3 marks)\\
(c) Third part (1 mark)\\

\textbf{Question 2 (10 marks)}

(a) First part (3 marks)\\
(b) Second part (4 marks)\\
(c) Third part (2 mark)\\
(d) Fourth part (1 mark)\\

\textbf{Question 3 (5 marks)}

\end{document}